# Cannot get data after translating table column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a question for a simple query. Lets say I have the table *colors*(color, code)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colors` (
  `color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with data:

```
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('blue', 'Conventional'), ('green', 'Realistic');
```

When I make a simple select query

```
SELECT * FROM colors WHERE code = 'Realistic';
```

I get the corresponding row.

Then, I translated the *code* column into greek. So I updated the *colors* table.

```
UPDATE colors set code = 'Συμβατικός' WHERE color = 'blue';
UPDATE colors set code = 'Ρεαλιστικός' WHERE color = 'green';
```

The table is succesfully updated. However, if I now make the query

```
SELECT * FROM colors WHERE code = 'Ρεαλιστικός';
```

I get no results!

Why could this happen? Is there any idea out there, because I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look in the DB for the row. What it has saved in DB?

Comment: In DB is saved exactly the data I want. I even copied the 'Ρεαλιστικός' and put it in the query, but no result was fetched!!

Comment: I just tried and it works fine here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41f05/1

Comment: I did exactly as I described above, but I can't understand why this is happening. If I change the language back to english, everything works fine. When I go back to greek, there is no result!! This is a very simple query to cause such trouble... Hearner, if I do the query in phpmyadmin, it works. It does not work through my .php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've stepped into the weird and wonderful world of UTF-8.

First thing to know is this:

**Setting your database collation to UTF-8 isn't enough.**

You need to pay attention to a few more things. My bet is that you forgot or didn't know about some of these things to remember. Try them and see if it helps.

- Modify your php.ini file to use UTF-8 as the default character set: `default_charset = "utf-8";`
- Set UTF-8 as the default character set for all MySQL connections (yes, your connections use a charset as well)
- On the MySQL side of things, modifications to the my.ini file may be required as follows:

  ```
  [client]
  default-character-set=UTF-8

  [mysql]
  default-character-set=UTF-8

  [mysqld]
  character-set-client-handshake = false #force encoding to uft8
  character-set-server=UTF-8
  collation-server=UTF-8_general_ci

  [mysqld_safe]
  default-character-set=UTF-8
  ```

  Restart your MySQL after you've made these changes.
- If the connecting client has no way to specify the encoding for its communication with MySQL, after the connection is established you may have to run the following command/query: `set names UTF-8;`

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not in localhost to be able to edit the files I need. I have my application on a hosting provider, where I can't access them. I have already `set names utf8` after my connection.

Comment: If things work with your phpMyAdmin, they should be able to work from your app as well. See if explicitly setting your MySQL connections in your PHP code to UTF-8 helps.

Comment: I have a .php file that connects to the database and is required in my application's .php files. What I have done is `$conn = mysql_connect( "provider", "database_user", "password") or die('Could not connect to server.' );`
`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`
`mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");`
`$selected = mysql_select_db("database_name",$conn)  or die("Could not select to database");`
Are these enough or do I have to do more? Thanks.

Comment: If you insist on using mysql_* functions, which isn't a good idea... `$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);`

Comment: This solved it finally!! @dinsdale you are a hero! Thank you very much!!

Comment: And I know that I have to change mysql_* functions. I will do this before my application goes online. Thank you again!